# Class "App\cat" not found (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\Blog\resources\views\layout\show.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

```php
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$post->id}}</th>
      <td><img src="{{asset('img/') . '/' .$post->file_path}}" width="100px " height="50px" class="img_table"></td>
       <td>{{$post->post_name}}</td>
      <td>{{$post->name}}</td>
      <td>  
        @if(strcmp($post->status , 'Published') == 0)
            <div class="btn btn-success">{{$post->status}}</div>
        @else
        <div class="btn btn-warning">{{$post->status}}</div>
        @endif </td>
         <td>{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
          <td>{{$post->slug}}</td>
          <td>{{$post->cat->game_category_id}}</td>

      <td><a href="" class="btn btn-info"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="/delete/{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
```

### Post Model

```php
        protected $table = 'posts';
        protected $fillable = [
            'post_name',
            'post_content',
            'name',
            'status',
            'file_path',
            'slug',
            'game_category_id'
    
        ];
      
     public function cat(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\cat');
     }
```

### Cat Model

```php
use HasFactory;
        protected $table = 'cats';
         protected $fillable = ['name','slug'];
    
    
         public function post(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\post');
         }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.. fix this `return $this->belongsTo('App\Cat');` here `C` should be capital

Answer (score 1):

Relationship model name is false, must be as the name of them Model
please use class `Cat::class` is better and readable

```
public function cat(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Cat::class);
    //return $this->belongsTo('App\Cat');
 }
```

Same for post

```
public function post(){
   return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<td>{{$post->cat->game_category_id}}</td>
```

to:

```
<td>{{$post->cat ? $post->cat->game_category_id : ''}}</td>
```

It first checks if the related `cat` exists, if it is, then gets the `id`, else it returns an empty string.

Comment: Didnt get the ans

Answer (score -1):

Attempt to read property "game_category_id" on null (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\Blog\resources\views\layout\show.blade.php)

Comment: Please don't use answers to comment further on your question, use comments